# MYSQL/PHP Try to calculate to columns if checkbox is check

Tags: php, mysql

i have in a table 5 columns
1. pret
2. avans
3. tax
4. withtax  (checkbox)
5. total

ia want to calculate total with 2 condition:
A. IF withtax is Checked then use formula:

```
$values['TOTAL'] = $values['PRET'] - $values['AVANS'];
```

B. IF withtax is unchecket then use formula:

```
$values['TOTAL'] = ($values['PRET'] + $values['TAX']) - $values['AVANS'];
```

**Please help**

Comment: [What you have tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/) PHP's [`if`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php)?

Comment: Post the html code and what you have tried also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the WITHTAX  is a boolean value. Then you can make the condition if to take the TAX value or 0 (zero).

```
$tax = $values['WITHTAX'] ? $values['TAX'] : 0;
```

And use your formula for both cases.

```
$values['TOTAL'] = ($values['PRET'] + $tax) - $values['AVANS'];
```

Is this what you are looking for ?

is it for each row of that table ? you would need to use a loop. Something like this:

```
foreach($values as $v){
    $tax = $v['WITHTAX'] ? $v['TAX'] : 0;
    $v['TOTAL'] = ($v['PRET'] + $tax) - $v['AVANS'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you send your formula with the POST method, so then you can do it in this way:

```
// if checkbox is checked
if(isset($_POST['withtax'])) {
  $values['TOTAL'] = $values['PRET'] - $values['AVANS'];
} else { // otherwise if it is unchecked
  $values['TOTAL'] = ($values['PRET'] + $values['TAX']) - $values['AVANS'];
}
```